# How to get rid of extra css files generated by running Grails app?

Tags: grails

When I'm running a Grails app, extra css files named main.css, mobile.css, and errors.css, get generated. However, main.css overrides the previous settings I have so I need to know how to keep them from being generated. This seems to happen only when I run the app from my instance so I think the problem is with my environment. What is causing these files to be generated and how do I keep that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

They are added when you do create-app, you can just delete these files and remove their usages from main.gsp layout.

Comment: This should solve your issue completely. Can you please mark Uday's answer as an answer, or do you still have an issue?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. These files don't show up in the project and I already took out the usages from main.gsp. So I don't know what exactly to delete. I'm really new to grails, so I really appreciate knowing where exactly to go and delete those files.

Comment: Have you checked the assets folder of your application, please check web-app folder as well.

Comment: web-app only has two tld files but with no mention of the css file in either. assets only contains my javascript, also nothing with the css file mentioned.